# Was there ever a voiced version of Monkey Island 2?

Tags: monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge

I have vague memories of Monkey Island 2 being fully voiced, but am worried that I might be slightly delusional.

Was there a voiced version of MI2 (prior to the Special Edition) or did the voice acting start in MI3?

Comment: Why are there votes to close this question as off topic?  It seems fine to me.

Comment: @SteveV. "off-topic", though I don't know why

Comment: @SteveV Some people think that asking "Does X exist" is off-topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wikipedia [states that MI3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curse_of_Monkey_Island) was the first in the series to feature voice acting:

> The Curse of Monkey Island was the first game in the series to feature voice acting.

The [MIWiki notes](http://www.miwiki.net/Monkey_Island_2:_LeChuck%27s_Revenge) that the voices were added in the special edition:

> Monkey Island 2 Special Edition: LeChuck's Revenge, released 19 years after the original game, uses updated graphics, **adds voice-overs** by many of the same actors as in the later games, [...]

From my personal memory, I don't recall it having voices.  This was somewhat unusual for a CDROM release from Lucasarts, as most of their CDROM releases were talkies...

Comment: MI2 was originally released on floppies, not CDs.

Comment: @KatieK, yes, but there was a CDROM release shortly thereafter.  Usually the CDROM editions of LucasArts games came with voice overs (like [Fate of Atlantis'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Fate_of_Atlantis) CDROM release in '92)

Comment: @agent86 - I don't recall a standalone CD version of Monkey Island 2, but there was a combination of 1 & 2 (which I think was re-released several times).  The first game (CD version) had an updated interface, and the second Monkey Island had better sound (I think the original floppy version used MIDI files).